# Loop VBA script

Tags: vba, excel

I borrowed code to split text from one cell by carriage returns, and it works excellently, but it works on the active cell only and I have a document with about 500 rows.

I tried to implement a loop function but the program just stops (hangs).

How do I implement a loop function or range function properly?

This is code I'm using:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    On Error Resume Next
    Call SplitText
End Sub

Sub SplitText()

    Dim str() As String

    If Len(ActiveCell.Value) Then      ' CHECK IF THE ACTIVE CELL IS NOT EMPTY.

        ' SPLIT THE ACTIVE CELL'S VALUE WITH LINE FEED (vbLf).
        str = VBA.Split(ActiveCell.Value, vbLf)

        ' REARRANGE TEXT TO MULTIPLE COLUMNS.
        ActiveCell.Resize(1, UBound(str) + 1).Offset(0, 1) = str

    End If

End Sub
```

This is how the table looks:

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5n5nd.png)

Comment: Because youre new to this, its worth pointing out the reason why it only works on active cell is due to "(ActiveCell.Value)." You'll notice the two answers you received make use of Selection or Arrays, which is technically what the issue was.

Comment: Thank you for valuable remarks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub SplitText()

Dim str() As String
Dim i As Long

i = 1 ' start at row 1
        Do
            If Len(Cells(i, "A").Value) Then     ' CHECK IF THE ACTIVE CELL IS NOT EMPTY.
                str = VBA.Split(Cells(i, "A"), vbLf) ' SPLIT THE ACTIVE CELL'S VALUE WITH LINE FEED (vbLf).
                Cells(i, "A").Resize(1, UBound(str) + 1).Offset(0, 1) = str  ' REARRANGE TEXT TO MULTIPLE COLUMNS.
            End If

            i = i + 1
        Loop Until IsEmpty(Cells(i, "A")) ' Loop until the first empty row

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanx, I have tried this option and it works fast and excellent.

Answer (score 0):

You can

- rewrite `SplitText()` to receive a range parameter and act on it
- do a loop in the calling program going across all selected cells

example:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim C As Range
    On Error Resume Next

    ' work on each cell within selected range
    For Each C In Selection.Cells
        SplitText C
    Next C

End Sub

Sub SplitText(Target As Range)
Dim str() As String

    If Len(Target.Value) Then      ' CHECK IF THE ACTIVE CELL IS NOT EMPTY.

        ' SPLIT THE ACTIVE CELL'S VALUE WITH LINE FEED (vbLf).
        str = VBA.Split(Target.Value, vbLf)

        ' REARRANGE TEXT TO MULTIPLE COLUMNS.
        Target.Resize(1, UBound(str) + 1).Offset(0, 1) = str

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Unclear exactly what range you want to loop through. You can easily use something like this though to loop through all the cells in a range:

```
Sub ProcessCells()
    Dim CellRange

    'Replace with whatever range you want to iterate over
    Set CellRange = Range("C13:F19")


    For Each cell In CellRange
        cell.Value = 10
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Just add the operations you want to perform on the cell inside the for loop, using cell to refere to the cell that is currently being processed, e.g.

```
str = VBA.Split(cell.Value, vbLf)
```

Comment: I thought that the script will take a lot more time to do the job, since the first part pulls information from the Internet and is quite slow, so the idea was to select only part of the column that I want to split (range A10:A50 and later A51:A80 etc.), not the entire column but since script works fast i don't need range function. Thanks anyway